# Copying Row of Data To New Sheet when checking the check box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have about 20 rows in 5 different sheets and I would like the row to copy to a separate sheet once I check the checkbox. I would like the rows to remain in its source sheet when the row is copied.

I found code that copies the entire row over the separate sheet and then copies the row back once it's un-checked, but it obviously needs tweaking to be applicable to my scenario. Here it is:

```
 function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheets named Brushed Nickel, Chrome, Matte Black, Brass/Gold, Tile and Paint
  // target sheet of move to named Desing Specs
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 11 or K
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Brushed Nickel", "Chrome", "Matte Black", "Brass/Gold", "Tile and Paint" && r.getColumn() == 11 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Desing Specs");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Desing Specs" && r.getColumn() == 11 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Brushed Nickel", "Chrome", "Matte Black", "Brass/Gold", "Tile and Paint");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Screen Shot:

[image]

Can someone please help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not just wrap the code in an `if` checking if the checkbox cell is `true`

Comment: This `ss.getSheetByName("Brushed Nickel", "Chrome", "Matte Black", "Brass/Gold", "Tile and Paint");`is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.range.getSheet();
  var shts=["Brushed Nickel", "Chrome", "Matte Black", "Brass/Gold", "Tile and Paint"];
  if(shts.indexOf(s.getName()!=-1) && e.range.columnStart==11 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var targetSheet=e.source.getSheetByName("Design Specs");
    var target=targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).copyTo(target);
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211254/discussion-on-answer-by-cooper-copying-row-of-data-to-new-sheet-when-checking-th).